# Child mouseEnabled

Tags: actionscript-3

There is a main CONTAINER which contains a lot of other movieclips, in these CHILD1 movieclips, there are a CUBE and an IMAGE movieclip too. I want to disable the mouse events for only the IMAGE movieclip, is it possible?

```
CONTAINER
 -CHILD1
  -CUBE //this has mouse events!
  -IMAGE //want to disable the mouse events for this!
 -CHILD2
  -CUBE //this has mouse events!
  -IMAGE //want to disable the mouse events for this!
 -CHILD3
  -CUBE //this has mouse events!
  -IMAGE //want to disable the mouse events for this!
```

Any idea? Thanks!
CHILD's code chunk:

```
private function added(e:Event) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, NEXT);
}
public function NEXT(e:MouseEvent) {
    //OB is the instance name of the IMAGE
    if(e.target.name == "OB"){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    }
    OB.gotoAndStop(Main.ID);
}
```

**[SOLVED]**
To disable a specific child's event listeneing:

```
private function added(e:Event) {
    mouseEnabled = false; //This is the clue.
    OB.mouseEnabled = false;
    OB.mouseChildren = false;
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);
    cube.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, NEXT);
}
```

Comment: So you are attaching the mouseEvent to the parent. Make sure that mouseChildren is set to false on OB.  And mouseEnabled is set to true.  Also, if OB is inside of CHILD, you should be able to use e.target == OB instead of the name property

Comment: I made an edit in my answer, please give a look.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, try putting a trace statement in your NEXT function.   trace(e.target) or trace(e.target.name) to see what is triggering the mouseEvent.

Comment: If I'm tracing e.target.name it's giving me OB(if I'm not clicking on the cube which is good). But still can't click through it.

Comment: Yep, but still can't click through it.

Comment: Oh right.  You don't want to stop propogation then, as that cancels the click event.

Comment: You should be attaching your mouseup listener on the CUBE itself and not the CHILD isntance.  And set OB.mouseEnabled/mouseChildren = false

Comment: Try my updated answer,  replacing CUBE with whatever your instance name of the CUBE is

Comment: Used the SAME code you wrote, and didn't work.

Comment: The code is from a big project, I can't.

Comment: Well, maybe this sample file I made can help you:  https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DE7E377292FE74C3!105

Comment: With your solved code, it's cleaner to have your mouse listener on the CUBE directly and not on CHILD.  You must have something else involved for it not to have worked that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your mouse listener is attached to the image, set the IMAGE's mouseEnabled & mouseChildren properties to false in the constructor (OR If using the timeline in Flash CSX) then on the IMAGE objects timeline (on the first frame) set mouseEnabled & mouseChildren to false.

HERE would be the changes to your posted code (not sure what you called your instance of CUBE):

```
private function added(e:Event) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);
    CUBE.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, NEXT);
    OB.mouseEnabled = false;
    OB.mouseChildren = false;
}
public function NEXT(e:MouseEvent) {
    OB.gotoAndStop(Main.ID);
}
```

Comment: The IMAGE is a movieclip, it has no class or anything but instance name. I tried to set the mouseEnabled and mouseChildren to false in it's timeline at the first frame, but nothing happened.

Comment: Where is your mouse event listener?  Is it attached to the parent clip (CHILD1 or CONTAINER) and you just don't want it to fire when clicking on IMAGE?

Comment: The listener is in EACH CHILD's class, your code example about stopping the propagation of the listener isn't what I'm searching for.
[IMAGE]
[[CUBE]]
[IMAGE]
[CUBE]

Let's say that the last CUBE is a movieclip, and the image is bigger than the CUBE, (the width of it), under the [IMAGE] there is an another [CUBE] (the [IMAGE] overlapping it)
I want to reach that [[CUBE]], need to be able to click it.

Comment: Then mouseEnabled = false and mouseChildren = false  (the first option in my answer) is how you achieve this.  You'll need to post actual code OR .fla for further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Give a instance name to your image(assuming it is "OB") and:

```
private function added(e:Event) 
{
    this.getChildByName("OB").mouseEnabled = false
    this.getChildByName("OB").mouseChildren = false; 
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, NEXT);    
}
```

If this doesn't work, probably you have other issues in your code and you should explain and show your code.